# List nodes by term on one page like Drupal 6

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I've searched through quite a lot of how to's now and completely stumped, In Drupal 6 with views the relative simple procedure of linking a taxonomy vocabulary to a content type then furthermore displaying it's terms on one page was a dazzle, now however in 7 running views 3+ not so simple.

I don't know if I'm searching for the wrong phase but literally this is what i want:

Content type = Article + Taxonomy vocabulary linked to content type "site content" > term "blog". Now I want to create a view with path /blog that lists all nodes with the term "blog", further down the line I want to add more entries to the "site content" e.g. "about" and link that to /about for example.

Comment: Have you add taxonomy as field to content type or not?

Comment: Yes the taxonomy is assigned to the content type

Answer (score 1):

OK, cracked it, here's what I did (sleep worked!):

1. Create taxonomy vocabulary and term (Structure > Add vocabulary > Add term (after))
2. Assign to content (Structure > Content Type > Article (for example in my case) > Manage Fields)
3. Type a label > Field Type "Term Reference" (The vocabulary from step 1) > Widget "Select List" > Save
4. Create the view (Structure > Views > + Add New View > Show "Content" > of type (select the type assigned in step 2) > Continue and edit
5. Under "Filter Criteria" > Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth) > Apply (All Displays) > Vocabulary (As created in step 1) > Apply and continue > In the field "Operator :: Is one of" > Type term (As created in step 1), then select from auto complete drop down > Apply (All Displays)

This will then show in the auto preview. I knew it was simple! - hope this helps someone else in my position.